# Xcode 5 iOS 7 - UIScrollView behaving oddly

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, xcode5

When migrating a project from Xcode 4 iOS 6, I noticed the UIScrollView instance is not behaving properly. Sometimes it just seems to be stuck, and only when I pinch in or out to change the scale does it start scrolling properly.

I noticed a few replies in a similar question, along the lines of removing positioning constraints, that I tried (even though I do need the constraints eventually) and it didn't work.

Has anyone encountered this behaviour and found a way to fix it?

Comment: Ensure `setContentSize` is in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and in `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`. In iOS6, if you didn't have the code in these methods, the default behaviour worked okay, in iOS7 with the new layout system, they are required.

Comment: Meant `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it may be called more than once for a setup, just keep calling `seContentSize`.

Comment: Thank you. Is working now. Would award you points but question was closed.

Comment: Can't add an answer, as it's closed, but for me the WTF was the need to set self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; In iOS7 it's default YES, but if you have nested scrollviews you may well need it set to NO. (I had no vert scrolling, but once horz scrolling started then vert became possible in iOS7, which was annoying. Changing this fixed it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure `setContentSize` is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and in `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`. In iOS6, if you didn't call `setContentSize` in these methods, the default behaviour worked okay, in iOS7 with the new layout system, they are required. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` may be called more than once for a setup, just keep calling `setContentSize`.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to make it work by using

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in the view controller holding the scrollview. Just put it after the scroll view's instantiation.

Comment: Looks promising, will try it out ASAP and let you know!